# How does the CPU "cast" a floating point x87 (i think) value?

Tags: c++, c, casting, x87

I just wanted to know how the CPU "Cast" a floating point number.
I mean, i suppouse that when when we use a "float" or "double" in C/C++ the compiler is using the x87 unit, or am i wrong? (i couldn't find the answer) So, if this is the case and the floating point numbers are not emulated how does the compiler cast it?

Comment: There are special instructions for converting, compiler only needs to emit them. Also, there is a difference between scalar and vector casts, but the time for manual conversion is long gone.

Comment: The compiler just has to store it in an appropriate format for the CPU to read. Then it points to this storage and basically says 'one [`fld`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5477/eoizy.html) please`.

Comment: Some processors have specific floating point registers, so that no "cast" is required.  A value is loaded directly from memory into the register or stored from the register directly into memory.

Comment: The "cast" operation tells the compiler to treat the variable differently.  Casting an integer to a double tells the compiler that you want the integer treated as a floating point.  The compiler may emit CPU instructions that convert from integer to floating point, or the compiler may convert the integer into floating point format, then store into register(s) or memory.

Comment: @usr2564301: The compiler does not need to convert the number itself. The x86 architecture has an `fild` instruction that loads an integer from memory and converts it to floating-point.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The phrasing “treat the variable differently” evokes the notion of reinterpreting bytes as a different type, but that is not a conversion from integer to floating-point entails. In a conversion to floating-point, a computation is performed whose input is the value in one format and whose output is the same value (as closely as possible) in another format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, i suppouse that when when we use a "float" or "double" in C/C++ the compiler is using the x87 unit, or am i wrong?

On modern Intel processors, the compiler is likely to use the SSE/AVX registers. The FPU is often not in regular use.

> I just wanted to know how the CPU "Cast" a floating point number.

Converting an integer to a floating-point number is a computation that is basically (glossing over some details):

- Start with the binary (for unsigned types) or two’s complement (for signed types) representation of the integer.
- If the number is zero, return all bits zero.
- If it is negative, remember that and negate the number to make it positive.
- Locate the highest bit set in the integer.
- Locate the lowest bit that will fit in the significand of the destination format. (For example, for the IEEE-754 binary32 format commonly used for `float`, 24 bits fit in the significand, so the 25<sup>th</sup> bit after the highest bit set does not fit.)
- Round the number at that position where the significand will end.
- Calculate the exponent, which is a function of where the highest bit set is. Add a “bias” used in encoding the exponent (127 for binary32, 1023 for binary64).
- Assemble a sign bit, bits for the exponent, and bits for the significand (omitting the high bit, because it is always one). Return those bits.

That computation prepares the bits that represent a floating-point number. (It omits details involving special cases like NaNs, infinities, and subnormal numbers because these do not occur when converting typical integer formats to typical floating-point formats.)

That computation may be performed “in software” (that is, with general instructions for shifting bits, testing values, and so on) or “in hardware” (that is, with special instructions for doing the conversion). All desktop computers have instructions for this. Small processors for special-purpose embedded use might not have such instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what do you mean by

> "Cast" a floating point number. ?

If target architecture has FPU then compiler will issue FPU instructions in order to manipulate floating point variables, no mistery there...
In order to assign float variable to int variable, float must be truncated or rounded(up or down). Special instructions usually exists to serve this purpose.

If target architecture is "FPU-less" then compiler(toolchain) might provide software implementation of floating point operations using CPU instructions available. For example, expression like a = x * y; will be equivalent to a = fmul(x, y); Where fmul() is compiler provided special function(intrinsic) to do floating point operations without FPU.  Ofcourse this is typically MUCH slower than using hardware FPU. Floating point arithmetic is not used on such platforms if performance matters, fixed point arithmetic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic could be used instead.